# How to grep for a string that includes "->"

Tags: c++, grep

I am looking for the literal string `->foo` in all the `*.cpp` files in a single directory.  If I try

```
grep -F "->foo" *.cpp
```

grep reports

```
Invalid option -- '>'
```

Then, if I try

```
grep -F "-\>foo" *.cpp
```

I get

```
Invalid option -- '\'
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally *(not `grep` specific)* using `--` signifies the end of options:

```
grep -F -- "->foo" *.cpp
```

Helpful when you accidentally create files starting with `-`:

```
$ touch -- -damn 

$ ls -- -*
-damn

$ rm -damn
rm: invalid option -- 'd'

$ rm -- -damn
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
grep -e "->foo" *.cpp
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> > -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
> >     Use PATTERN as the pattern. This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to **protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-)**. (-e is specified by POSIX .) [emphasis added]